# responsive full screen html5 video

Tags: html, css, html5-video, fullscreen

I want to make a full screen responsive banner video like https://yourkarma.com/. I make the same..but the problem is when I checked  in mobile and tab view the video height going to reduce.so did some changes in my css, then I get the result but lost major portion of the video in mobile and tab view  . how can I achieve that similar to my reference site?

css

---

```
.main_banner{
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#141517;   
}
.main_banner video{
    width:auto;
}
```

html

```
<section class="main_banner">
        <video autoplay loop preload>
          <source src="videos/Meet_Eric_at_Aditi_Staffing_MP4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="videos/Meet_Eric_at_Aditi_Staffing_Ogv.ogv" type="video/ogg">
          <source src="videos/Meet_Eric_at_Aditi_Staffing_Webm.webm" type="video/webm">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </section>
```

Comment: why not use media query?

Comment: used media query..but how can achieve with media query??? in mobile  and tab view  I need the video with full screen.

Comment: do u mean media query didn't work or you don't really know how to make it fit with media query

Comment: I mean the video not fit in the small size devices...the peoples are not visible in video, this is the demo link :http://jsfiddle.net/55j7xch1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should leave out the `height:100%`.
If you want it to be responsive and use the full height of the screen use `top:0; bottom:0`. 
This requires position:absolute or relative iirc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the video not fit in small size device,bcoz i give width:auto and overflow hidden...else the video height reduce when the screen reduce..any option to  skew the video?..this is the demo link : http://jsfiddle.net/55j7xch1/.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is not that it doesn't fill the screen. What about using different videos for different viewscopes? Like using that larger video in Desktop view, but using a video designed for mobile phones for smaller devices? Otherwise the video will get skewed if you make it scale down AND use the full height.

Comment: sorry...we can use different videos..only one is possible....is there is any option to achieve?

Comment: Hmm you could push the video farther to the left for small devices.  This would make the person visible. Tried it with a negative margin-left. That way the video moves left. This allows you to see the person speaking. The problem with that however is, that you can't read the text in the end of the video. So thats not a good way also. If you want the whole video to be visible you have to scale it I think. That will make it use less height, but at least you are not missing any content. Every other solution i can think of atm is either skewing the video, or leaving some things out of view port...